# Overspecification Bayesian mixed linear model

Tags: regression, bayesian

I am trying to estimate a mixed linear regression model with an individual intercept using JAGS in a Bayesian way. Therefore, I simulate data as presented and estimate the model. The code is adjusted to several examples I found in different tutorials. Nevertheless, it does not seem right to me regarding the results showing clear signs of biased estimation. Therefore I am wondering, if I am doing something wrong here or if there are other problems I am not aware of, e.g., overspecification, prior choice, etc.

Is someone familiar with this type of problem and can help me? Here is my example code:

```
#fixed effects
beta <- c(7, 2)

#standard deviation of Y
sigma <- 3

#standard deviation of individual intercept
sigma_u <- 1

#Number of individuals
J <- 20

#Measurements per Individual
K <- 2

#treatment and no treatment for individual
cwi <- rep(0:1, J * K)

#individual id
ind <- c()
for(i in 1:J){
  ind <- c(ind, rep(i, K))  
}

#simualte data
set.seed(42)
eps <- rnorm(J*K, mean = 0, sd = sigma)
random_effects <- rnorm(J, mean = 0, sd = sigma_u)

y <- c()
for(i in 1:(J*K)){
  y[i] <- beta[1] + random_effects[ind[i]] + beta[2] * cwi[i] + epsilon[i]
}

head(data.frame('ID' = ind, 'cwi' = cwi, 'y' = y))


#define model
model_string <- "model{

  # Likelihood
  for(i in 1:N){

    Y[i]   ~ dnorm(mu[i], inv_var)
    mu[i] <- beta[1] + u[ind[i]] + beta[2]*cwi[i]

  }

  for(j in 1:J){
        u[j] ~ dnorm(0, inv_var_u)
  }

  # Prior for beta
  for(j in 1:2){
    beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,1)
  }

  # Prior for the inverse variance
  inv_var   ~ dgamma(1, 1)
  sigma     <- 1/sqrt(inv_var)

  # Prior for the random effect
  inv_var_u ~ dgamma(1, 1)
  sigma_u <- 1/sqrt(inv_var_u)

}"

library(rjags)
#compile model
model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_string), 
                    data = list(Y = y, N = J*K, J = 20, ind = ind, cwi = cwi))


#draw samples
update(model, 10000); # Burnin for 10000 samples

samp <- coda.samples(model, 
                     variable.names=c("beta","sigma", "sigma_u"), 
                     n.iter=20000, n.thin = 10, n.chain = 2)

#output
summary(samp)

Iterations = 10001:30000
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 1 
Sample size per chain = 20000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

         Mean     SD Naive SE Time-series SE
beta[1] 4.272 0.9035 0.006389       0.018755
beta[2] 1.431 0.6697 0.004736       0.007554
sigma   2.924 0.5169 0.003655       0.010223
sigma_u 2.464 1.1453 0.008098       0.034553

2. Quantiles for each variable:

          2.5%    25%   50%   75% 97.5%
beta[1] 2.2550 3.7309 4.357 4.902 5.813
beta[2] 0.1439 0.9713 1.423 1.873 2.762
sigma   2.0971 2.5465 2.866 3.235 4.086
sigma_u 0.7085 1.6154 2.334 3.155 5.056
```

Especially the estimation of the random effects variance and its impact on the fixed intercept seem wrong to me.

Comment: you have added quite informative prior on the variance terms; try for example, `beta[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.001)` and `inv_var   ~ dgamma(.001, .001)`

Comment: Thanks, that helped!